# configuration was not valid for plugin 'overthere-winrm': hostnameVerify: Invalid value: BROWSER_COMPATIBLE

Tags: rundeck, winrm, overthere

I have windows node defined as follows

```
  "goodhost":{
      "description":"File host",
      "hostname":"goodhost",
      "node-executor":"overthere-winrm",
      "file-copier":"overthere-winrm",
      "nodename":"goodhost",
      "osArch":"amd64",
      "osFamily":"windows",
      "osName":"Windows Server",
      "osVersion":"2019",
      "username":"user1",
      "winrm-auth-type":"basic",
      "winrm-cmd":"PowerShell",
      "winrm-kerberos-debug":"true",
      "winrm-password-storage-path":"keys/windows_passwrod",
      "winrm-protocol":"http"
   },
```

However when I try to execute any command I get below error.

```
[2023-06-02T00:10:56,814] ERROR services.PluginService - NodeExecutor: configuration was not valid for plugin 'overthere-winrm': hostnameVerify: Invalid value: BROWSER_COMPATIBLE
certTrust: Invalid value: STRICT
```

In the [official documentation](https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/rundeck-winrm-plugin) of plugin there is no mention of these parameters so I am not sure what's the issue here?

Comment: That plugin is outdated and it's no longer maintained by the Rundeck dev team. Also, some problems has been reported with recent Rundeck versions: http://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/8148#issuecomment-1443678921. Please use the PyWinRM (out of the box with Rundeck since version 3.0), take a look at this: https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/py-winrm-plugin#rundeck-python-winrm-plugin

Comment: @MegaDrive68k tried it too but facing another issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76391164/change-default-pywinrm-interpreter-in-node-definition

Comment: I see, currently isn't implemented (I answered your question). I guess the best approach right now is to use separate projects for your windows machines. Anyway, it seems a good plugin enhacement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That plugin is outdated and it's no longer maintained by the Rundeck dev team. Also, some problems like [this](https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/8148#issuecomment-1443678921) one has been reported with recent Rundeck versions. No fixes are expected for that plugin.

Please use the PyWinRM (out of the box with Rundeck since version 3.0), take a look at [this](https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/py-winrm-plugin).